# How to X11 forward after multi hopping in SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, port-forwarding, xorg

I have the following SSH flow: `root@HostA -> root@HostB -> root@HostC -> user@HostD`

I want to do X11 forwarding for Firefox on HostD all the way back to HostA, since A, B and C don't have access to the internet.

I've been facing a few issues, so I decided to solve it step by step. Taking into account that all commands are being executed on HostA, here is my process:

TERMINAL 1

```
A$ su -
A$ ssh -L 2222:HostB:3333 root@HostB -N
```

TERMINAL 2

```
A$ su -
A$ ssh root@HostB
B$ ssh -L 3333:HostC:4444 root@HostC -N
```

TERMINAL 3

```
A$ su -
A$ ssh root@HostB
B$ ssh root@HostC
C$ ssh -L 4444:HostD:22 user@HostD -N
```

TERMINAL 4

```
A$ su -
A$ ssh -X -p 2222 user@localhost
```

After executing the last command on TERMINAL 4, I receive the following error:

`ssh _exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

And on TERMINAL 1, it shows the following message:

`channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`

I have already tried reorganizing all ports and I know the process above is too repetitive, but I wanted to make sure I covered everything, but I can't seem to find the error. What am I doing wrong?

I also have an old version of SSH, so I could not use -J option, for example. Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I made sure that every host had X11Forwarding, AllowTcpForwarding and GatewayPorts set as *yes* on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and then restarted sshd service.
This time, I have made a few more tests.

**TEST 1**

TERMINAL 1: `A$ ssh -L 2222:HostB:22 root@HostB -N`

TERMINAL 2: `A$ ssh -Y -p 2222 root@localhost`

And it works!

**TEST 2**

TERMINAL 1: `A$ ssh -L 2222:HostB:3333 root@HostB -N`

TERMINAL 2: `B$ ssh -L 3333:HostC:22 root@HostC -N`

TERMINAL 3: `A$ ssh -Y -p 2222 root@localhost`

And it gives me the previous error.

**TEST 3**

TERMINAL 1: `B$ ssh -L 3333:HostC:22 root@HostC -N`

TERMINAL 2: `A$ ssh -p 3333 root@HostB`

And it also gives me the previous error.

So I'm having a hard time with the second local port forwarding. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use the `-Y` flag to enable trusted X11 forwarding. Ensure also that X11Forwarding is enabled everywhere and AllowTcpForwarding is yes and GatewayPorts is yes. See [link1](https://serverfault.com/questions/53080/how-to-enable-ssh-x11-forwarding-through-additional-server) and [link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/585331/forwarding-x11-with-one-hop-without-x-server-installed).

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your answer! I edited my question with a few updates. I made sure to update all hosts as you have said, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: First thing is to replace each syntax in the form of `-L NNNN:HostX:MMMM root@HostX` with `-L NNNN:localhost:MMMM root@HostX`, because the next leg of the daisy-chained tunnel you're building will most likely listen on the loopback interface (of `HostX`), but *not necessarily* on the outside interface (of `HostX`).